# In Flutter how can we translate the searchFieldLabel in the delegate of the showSearch() widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization, intl

I have the following code to generate a `showSearch()` widget

```
onTap: () {
    showSearch(
        context: context,
        delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(),
        query: '',
    );
},
```

Now in the `CustomSearchDelegate` I have the following code in the contructor which needs to be translated.

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
    CustomSearchDelegate()
      : super(
          searchFieldLabel: Translations.of(context).searchAnyKeyword,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
        );
```

Now the issue is that I need the `context` to perform translations as it is mentioned [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

The delegate definitely has the `context` as we use it in the `build` functions. The question is how to access it in the constructor?